Advice needed on cleaning up storage on Windows 11 Home 23H2M (64 bit) after upgrading from Windows 10?
I’m a recent convert Windows 10 to 11. My 2015 HP laptop (4.0GB  2.20GZ) is bulging about now.
I want to clean out anything I can.
Storage has multi old Micro C Vis postings. I know you can delete them but which are required to keep ?

"Disk Clean-Up"?

“Micro C Vis postings” - No idea what you mean by this statement

Welcome to Superuser. Please avoid using acronyms or shortened forms of words unless you've clearly defined them earlier in the question. Also, the word "bulging" when referring to a laptop usually means a very different thing, so if you mean the Disk is running out of space, say that, and do not say "bulging" unless you mean the laptop is actually swelling like a balloon (and if it IS literally swelling, you should turn it off and take it to service immediately).

This question is similar to: How do I delete Windows.old in Windows?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I am guessing, but after a major Windows upgrade like Win10 to Win11 the single largest folder you can remove to free up space is Windows.old. I have marked this as a duplicate of another question dealing with this folder. If you have already removed (or don't have) a Windows.old folder, let us know.

Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable is installed by the program that need the specific version of it to run, and it don't take much of the memory so you should leave them be.
What you should do is:

Remove unnecessary program on your C drive or move it to other drive.
Clean up Downloads/Documents/Pictures/RecycleBin/etc... that using your C drive.
Maybe zipping the files of C to make spaces.



Do you perhaps mean "compressing the files of C"? While Zip is compressing, not all compressing is Zip, and you really DON'T want to recommend people actually Zip C drive contents.

Yeah but that's 1 way to reduce C usage.

Not a practical method. Enabling compression is one way to reduce used space, and for many people it's a perfectly good method too, with few downsides. Zipping the contents of C drive, though, is impossible without booting to an alternative environment not running on that C drive, and renders the OS installed to C drive unusable, so no, it is not a VALID way to free up space on a functional system you wish to remain functional. Perhaps this is a language issue, but "Compression" in THIS context, and "Zipping" are not the same thing.
